# verifying cookbooks for windows using opscode's hosted chef

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-infra

I have few cookbooks which have to be verified only for Windows.Basically running the recipes and see

**I am using opscode's hosted chef.**

For doing this, which combination shall I use :

a) windows workstation(for uploading recipes to server), ubuntu chef client node.

b) windows workstation , windows chef client node.

I am actually very new to the chef.Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

In your case for simply verifying Windows recipes/cookbooks work, I highly recommend using chef-solo. You don't need to set up an entire chef server to prove everything works (unless that requirement is being forced on you):

http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html

Running is as simple as:

```
chef-solo -c C:/chef/solo.rb -j C:/chef/solo.json
```

Where solo.rb is your configuration file and solo.json contains your run list and attributes.

If you do need a chef server... it doesn't really matter if you run it on Windows or Linux, just choose whatever is going to be easiest for you. Regardless the client will need to be installed on your Windows workstation.

http://docs.opscode.com/install_workstation.html

http://docs.opscode.com/install_windows.html